# O que é SEO, é possível deixar um site no topo dos resultados do Google em pouco tempo?

Tags: html, google, seo, html-meta-tag

Está é minha dúvida a algum tempo. O que é SEO, como criar meta tags para deixar o site visível no google ?  Como utilizar SEO?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info É possível fazer o que deseja. Não será com meta-tags. Está respondido?

Comment: bigown, deixa me ver se entendi, então a busca é realizado em relação ao conteudo da página, titulo etc ?